# Error: Fatal error: Interface 'PHPExcel_Reader_IReadFilter' not found in D:\xampp\htdocs\Tests\example1.php on line 10

Tags: php, phpexcel

Here's my code I copied from the documentation of PHPExcel. I'm trying to read specific cell values. Any help will be appreciated.

```
<?php

$inputFileType = 'Excel2007';
$inputFileName = 'cohort1.xlsx';
$sheetname = 'Sheet1';


/**  Define a Read Filter class implementing PHPExcel_Reader_IReadFilter  */ 
class MyReadFilter implements PHPExcel_Reader_IReadFilter
{
    public function readCell($column, $row, $worksheetName = 'Sheet1') {
        //  Read rows 1 to 7 and columns A to E only 
        if ($row >= 1 && $row <= 7) {
            if (in_array($column,range('A','E'))) {
                return true;
            } 
        }
        return false; 
    } 
} 

/**  Create an Instance of our Read Filter  **/ 
$filterSubset = new MyReadFilter(); 

/**  Create a new Reader of the type defined in $inputFileType  **/ 
$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType); 
/**  Tell the Reader that we want to use the Read Filter  **/ 
$objReader->setReadFilter($filterSubset); 
/**  Load only the rows and columns that match our filter to PHPExcel  **/ 
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($inputFileName); 


?>
```

I have an excel file that I want to read using PHP. It's a pretty big table that's why I decided to use excel instead of database tables.

I would also like to know if there is any other better way of doing this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to `include()` the file that defines the PHPExcel_Reader class.

If you want to read a lot of data, you might consider saving the Excel file in .csv format (comma separated value).  Then you can use `fgetcsv()` and `fputcsv()` and iterate across the file one row at a time.

If you want anything more specific, we'll need more detail on what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

Include the PHPExcel class itself before defining your read filter: that will enable the autoloader, which should then be able to find all the core PHPExcel class files, including PHPExcel_Reader_IReadFilter.